# How to modify css in OpenERP 7?

Tags: python, css, xml, odoo

here is my requirement.i already created worker registration screen.its shows below

[image]

i need to change align and set EPF No field after Employer No field(with no label).

here shows my code in view.xml

```
<field name="employer_no" style="width: 30%%" />
<field name="epf_no" style="width: 30%%" class="bpl_worker_epf_no" />
```

i tried with css file.but its not affected to field.its just changed my field's label color.

```
.bpl_worker_epf_no {
    color: blue;
    top: 255px;
    left: 45px
}
```

please help me to sort out this issue.when i tried with nolabel="1" its messed up my layout and some fields arranged incorrect pattern.then please help me to sort this issue

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's a bit to late, but you could have done something like:

```
<label for="field_B"/>
<div>
   <field name="field_A" class="oe_inline"/>
   <field name="field_B" class="oe_inline"/>
</div>
```

And you'll get the desire output.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's not such option by default. Have a look at this http://planet.domsense.com/en/2012/09/openerp-custom-fields-colors-and-styles/. Never tried on v7 though.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with the headers in the tree view all being left justified while the number fields below them were right justified.

I was able to make css adjustments by modifying the base.css file adding the following entries:

```
.oe_list_header_integer {
    text-align: right;
}

.oe_list_header_float {
    text-align: right;
}

.oe_list_header_char {
    text-align: left;
}
```

and deleting the left justifying entry here which was overriding my adjustments above

```
.openerp th, .openerp td {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```